# Timing a Function in Python

Tags: python, search, recursion, time

I'm trying to time two different functions in python.

The first:

```
import cProfile
def bin_search(A, first,last, target):
#returns index of target in A, if present
#returns -1 if target is not present in A
if first > last:
    return -1
else:
    mid = (first+last)/2
    if A[mid]==target:
        return mid
    elif A[mid]>target:
        return bin_search(A,first,mid-1,target)
    else:
        return bin_search(A,mid+1,last,target)
```

the second

```
def trin_search(A,first,last,target):
#returns index of target in A, if present
#returns -1 if target is not present in A
if target> last or target<first:
    return -1
if first>last:
    return -1
else:
    one_third=first+(last-first)/3
    two_thirds=first+2*(last-first)/3
    if A[one_third]==target:
        return one_third
    elif A[one_third]>target:
        #search the left-hand third
        return trin_search(A,first, one_third,target)
    elif A[two_thirds]==target:
        return two_thirds
    elif A[two_thirds]>target:
        #search the middle third
        return trin_search(A,one_third+1,two_thirds-1,target)
    else:
        #search the right-hand third
        return trin_search(A,two_thirds+1,last,target)
```

I'm trying to time them using the cprofile.run() method. I call:

```
cprofile.run('trin_search(newlist, newlist[0], newlist[-1], 17)')
```

and

```
cprofile.run('bin_search(newlist, newlist[0], newlist[-1], 17)')
```

with the results for the first:

```
6 function calls (4 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
  3/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Jan 18.py:16(trin_search)
    0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 profile:0(trin_search(newlist, newlist[0], newlist[-1], 17))
```

and the second

```
7 function calls (3 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
  5/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Jan 18.py:2(bin_search)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

How is it possible that they take 0 time to operate?

Cheers,

Comment: Usually, timing is best done with `timeit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out by other use the `timeit` module, here's an example how to time a function with parameters:

```
import timeit

arg = 10

def foo(arg):
    return arg**arg

t=timeit.Timer("foo(arg)","from __main__ import foo, arg")
print t.timeit(5)
```

Note that you have to import both the function and the variables that you are using in your function call.

Also, I would suggest that you use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) where you have *"magic commands"* so you can simply do `%timeit foo(arg)`.

---

For your example, this should work:

```
t=timeit.Timer("bin_search(newlist, newlist[0], newlist[-1], 17)",
                       "from __main__ import bin_search, newlist")
```

Comment: I'm trying to run t=timeit.Timer("bin_search(newlist, newlist[0],newlist[-1],17)","from__main__import bin_search")

Comment: Yeah Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    t=timeit.Timer("bin_search(newlist, newlist[0],newlist[-1],17)","from__main__import bin_search")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\timeit.py", line 136, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 3
    from__main__import bin_search
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Unknown -- you do have spaces between `from, __main__, import`, etc right? Also the string should be self contained without references to other objects like `newlist`.

Comment: @Unknown --  added your example to the answer.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work with your example, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.  It is made for benchmarking code snippets.

Comment: I've been looking at the timeit module for a bit. Especially this: http://www.diveintopython.net/performance_tuning/timeit.html but I'm not sure how to call my function from the module.